# TOpendialog in Delphi XE7(up1) on Mac has something wrong?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

TOpendialog in Delphi XE7 or Delphi XE7 UP1 on Mac (yosemite) has something wrong.
After `Opendialog1.execute` , the whole form will have some strange problem and sometimes the application will crash.

I tried the same app on another Mac which is running Mavericks, it works fine.

Here is one source code.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenDialog1.Execute;
end;

end.
```

And here is what Paserver shows:

> Process Control Server Started pid 884 exe  built Jul 18 2014
>
> sentinelFunc 886
>
> 2014-12-02 21:24:19.360 Project1[888:27602] --ImageKit Error: updateGLTextureWithBitmapData: glPixelStorei returned an error : 502 (subSize=[64.000000,64.000000] offset [704.000000,0.000000] glID:1, context:0x1326c930)

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? Why ask again?

Comment: That question was deleted, they said I did't give the source code. I don't know what I did is allowed, Sorry.

Comment: So now we have to delete it again? And write all the comments again? I suggest that you submit this issue to Quality Portal. Did you do that yet? If not, why not?

Comment: Could you please tell me why?

Comment: Please expand on what that comment means.

Comment: Do I need to zip a project then post here?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English. I just want to know what mistake I made or how to make the question clear?

Comment: No, don't ZIP up a project. Condense your code down to just a handful of lines. I guess you can do this with a plain vanilla FMX app and a single form. Include the code for the .pas file and .dfm file in the question, by way of an edit.

Comment: However, I ask again, and I really hope that you answer this time. Did you submit the issue to Quality Portal yet? If not, why not? Remember that the Stack Overflow community cannot fix bugs in Embarcadero's product. You have to report the issue to the vendor.

Comment: It is also pretty poor that when your question is closed and you are told that it needed to contain code, you fail to heed that advice. You might not like that advice, but nobody is forcing you to post here. When the community says that code is needed in your question, you should respect that. You are new to this site, as you mention. Let the community guide you in how to use it. Remember that the people here have a lot of experience in answering questions. They know what they are doing. Please listen to and heed the advice you have received.

Comment: I'm sorry the mistake that I made, I have changed the question, but I think I already give the code. Actually I am a freashman of Delphi, so I am not sure is this a bug or something else.

Comment: If this is a bug of Delphi, I will try to submit it to Quality Portal.

Comment: This is much better. Well done. It looks like a bug to me. I'd certainly submit it to Quality Portal.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry to bother you for such a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue on my system. So I doubt that this is a problem with your code.

Have you tried resetting the PRAM of your Mac? If that got messed up somehow, you might have issues like the one you described.
http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222

Comment: Thank you. This problem is showed with Delphi app only. The system that I used is Yosemite, but I don't have another system to test.